# Cannot reuse a single variable in for loop

Tags: pointers, go, closures

I want to create a pointer and use it in every iteration but in the and I get all the same values. So I found the solution using creating the pointer in every iteration.
But this approach seems wasting a lot of memory.

Is there a way to reuse the same variable in Go?

Here is my code

```
func GetSchedules(start, end time.Time, usr *user.User) ([]*Scheduler, error) {
    queryStr := []string{"SELECT account_id,link,text,time,image_links from", Table, "where user_id=?"}
    var results = make([]*Scheduler, 0)
    rows, err := DB.MYSQL_DB.Query(strings.Join(queryStr, " "), usr.Id.Hex())
    if nil != err {
        return results, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    a := new(Scheduler)
    for rows.Next() {
        
        cols := []interface{}{&a.AccountId, &a.Link, &a.Text, &a.Time, &a.Images}
        fmt.Println(rows.Scan(cols...))
        results = append(results, a)

    }

    return results, nil
}
```

hereThe problem is with the variable called `a` although I am scanning new stuff into it in every iteration it just keeps showing the last one and the  results slice contains just the last item multiple times

Comment: The above code should give you different values, since you allocate `a` in every iteration. So which one is the problem?

Comment: yes it does but i dont want to allocate everytime because if i allocate everytime it means i need to free everytime and this cant be done in go and so gc will interfere more @putu

Comment: i just updated code to the one that doesnt work so it wont be confusing any more

Comment: You can't create 1 value, and somehow have that be multiple different values. Create the values you need, and don't worry about GC. If GC is a problem for some reason, make an example showing that particular problem.

Comment: @JimB the point is that i have created a single variable but i am updating it inside the array and just there i am appending that i wanna append the value not a reference to the actual variable and while writing this comment i just understood what to do thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about GC until you have proof that it is a bottleneck in your application. When reading data from DB, GC will never be a bottleneck for you. This is a simple benchmark:

```
func BenchmarkReallocate(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        results := make([]*foo, 0)
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            f := new(foo)
            f.bar = "baz"
            results = append(results, f)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkReuse(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        results := make([]*foo, 0)
        var f *foo
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            f = new(foo)
            f.bar = "baz"
            results = append(results, f)
        }
    }
}
```

Results of running `go test -bench . -benchmem`:

```
BenchmarkReallocate-8         300000          4416 ns/op        3640 B/op        108 allocs/op
BenchmarkReuse-8              300000          4359 ns/op        3640 B/op        108 allocs/op
PASS
```

So in the end both ways result in exactly the same amount of allocations.

And the typical reading from DB into struct looks like this:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM foo")
if nil != err {
    return nil, err
}
defer rows.Close()
results := make([]*Scheduler, 0)
for rows.Next() {
    var s Scheduler
    if err := rows.Scan(&s.Id, &s.Name, &s.Something); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    results = append(results, &s)
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil { // Don't forget to check rows.Err()
    return nil, err
}
return results, nil
```